# how to run count down timer when app is closed in flutter

Tags: flutter, background, countdowntimer, close-application

Flutter how to run count down timer when the app is closed, I tried but timer each and every time starts from initial stage when I remove app from background

Answer (score 0):

To run the countdown timer in the background, you can use the **`android_alarm_manager`** package. This package allows you to schedule tasks that continue running even when the app is closed. By adding this package it with your countdown timer logic, you can ensure that the timer keeps running in the background.

please implement below code accordingly

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Countdown Timer',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: CountdownScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class CountdownScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CountdownScreenState createState() => _CountdownScreenState();
}

class _CountdownScreenState extends State<CountdownScreen> {
  int _duration = 60;
  Timer _timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startCountdown();
  }

  void startCountdown() {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      if (_duration <= 0) {
        timer.cancel();
        // Timer finished
        print('Countdown complete!');
      } else {
        setState(() {
          // Update timer display or perform other actions
          print('Time remaining: $_duration seconds');
          _duration--;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Countdown Timer'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Time remaining: $_duration seconds',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this is helpful for you.